# Traversing a circularly doubly linked list

Tags: c++

So I'd like to return the element at index i from the header.
There is no trailer node in this doubly linked list - the last node connects with the header node.

For example, consider this circularly doubly linked list:

```
index:.......[0].........[1].........[2].........[3]

Header <=> [a|543] <=> [b|234] <=> [c|876] <=> [d|456]
  ^ ==============================================^
```

- If I wanted to retrieve the element at index `i = 2`, the result would be `876`.
- If I wanted to retrieve the element at index `i = 4`, the result would be `543` (the list loops around, but skips the header).

I've developed this logic:

```
Elem&
CircleList::operator [] (int i) const{
    CNode* temp; // Creating temporary node for traversal purposes
    temp->next = header; // Setting it equal to the header
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) { // Traverses up to i'th node
        if (temp->next == header) {
            temp = temp->next->next; // Skips the header
        }
        else {
            temp = temp->next; // Iterates to the next node
        }
    }
    return temp->elem; // Returns the element within that node
}
```

I've made a new node and set that equal to the header. Then I am attempting to traverse using a for-loop. However, I'm totally unsure if this method would even be possible as I don't have the means to test it yet.

- Am I on the right track or is this just plain wrong?

Comment: This is plain wrong. This code will crash on the second line. `CNode *temp;` does not "create a temporary node". It creates an uninitialized pointer. The next statement dereferences it. This results in undefined behavior, and a likely crash. And that's just one of the multiple problems that I see here, including confusion between `=` and `==`, etc...

Comment: There is **no** other way of knowing other than testing. Whoever tells you differently, run away from them. You **can't** harm a computer or your OS installation by doing these kind of experiments. The way you're approaching it right now, you're wasting time in the theory, believe me. Go out and test!

Comment: It can be optimized if there is a possibly known list length. And it's a bit misleading to use `operator[]` for anything with linear complexity or worse. And it uses an uninitialized variable `temp`. But apart from that it looks OK. Voted to close as too broad.

Comment: There is an error with `==` vs `=` in the `if` condition. Beware!

Comment: I think I fixed the '=' to '==' problem. So my main goal now is to figure out how to create a temp node to traverse. Sam stated that CNode *temp is completely wrong. Any hints? Also we are not given the list length to my knowledge.

Comment: Your idea is basically correct now. But you need to test. And as others has pointed out, your code contains many basic errors. Fix it before test your algorithm. You're on the right track.

Comment: Store node count in the header, then use the count to limit iterations as `i % count`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight do you think it would be possible to just move linearly in memory or is it too much to require a linear layout?

Comment: Linked lists do not have linear layout, so the answer to this one is "no".

Comment: You say you've got a double linked list, but you're never setting a previous pointer.  You don't show the class definition, either.